# Determine all possible values of $\int_\limits{\gamma} \sin(\frac{1-z}{z})dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Determine all possible values of  $\int_\limits{\gamma} \sin(\frac{1-z}{z})dz$ for a closed path $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

My thoughts on this exercise were that since $0$ is an essential singularity I can't calculate the residue through differentiation. But I know that the residue of a function is the $(-1)$-coefficient of the laurent series.

Therefore the value of the integral is $0$ for all paths which don't enclose the origin and $\nu_\gamma(0) c_{-1}$ for all other closed paths in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Where  $\nu_\gamma(0)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ around $0$ and $c_{-1}$ is the $(-1)$-laurent coefficient.

I would appreciate an opinion on my thoughts or some help if I'm incorrect.

Comment: It looks fine so far...what about $\;c_{-1}\;$ in case zero is enclosed by the closed path? Try to do a Laurent series for $\;\sin\frac{1-z}z\;$ about $\;z=0\;$  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{1-z}{z}\right)&=\cos\left(1\right)\sin\left(\frac1z\right)-\sin\left(1\right)\cos\left(\frac1z\right)\\\\
&=\cos(1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!z^{2n+1}}-\sin(1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!z^{2n}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you very much - the was the missing piece.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.